# Can a udp connection be made from an ASP based website to a winform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I need to know if a UDP connection can be made from an ASP based webform written on vs 2013 to a server winform also written in VS 2013. The hosting for the site works through plesk panel and both are written in vb.

Locally they do communicate but as soon as the website is published, no data is received on the server side.

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need code examples.

Comment: Do both reside on the same server? In other words, the server that is hosting the ASP also hosts the Winform App?

Comment: No they dont. Sorry it took so long to respond.

Comment: To clarify. The hosting is done by domains.co.za and the server winform will be on a private pc converted to a server. Then a variable number of client winforms would be connecting to the server winform also using UDP (these have no problem communicating).